# Keyboard shortcut to play animations in the timeline in reverse?

Tags: animation, shortcut

To play an animation (physics simulation, etc.) I usually use <kbd>Option(Alt)</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

Is there an easy way to play the animation backwards with a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some vigorous button pressing, I found this

<kbd>Option(Alt)</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

It behaves the exact same way as <kbd>Option(Alt)</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, except the animation plays backwards.

Answer (score 7):

To find shortcuts you can just enable tooltips on the user preferences:

[image]

Then just hover over the function you need a popup tooltip will appear with the keyboard shortcut:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

This will play your animation backwards from whatever point your animation is at currently.